# Scroll all the way down to the bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` and I'm trying to load 36 rows into it and then scroll all the way down the last cell.

I've tried this:

```
func reloadData(){
    chatroomTableView.reloadData()
    chatroomTableView.scrollToBottom(true)
}


extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        let sections = self.numberOfSections
        let rows = self.numberOfRowsInSection(sections - 1)
        if (rows > 0){
            self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: rows - 1, inSection: sections - 1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

But it only scrolls down halfway.

Comment: Does `rows` and `sections` have the expected value in your `scrollToBottom` function when it's called?

Comment: Yes, rows = 36 and sections = 1. Yet it only scrolls to row 10 of section 0.

Comment: Try wrapping your call to `scrollToBottom` inside a `dispatch_async` or maybe `dispatch_after`.

Comment: With dispatch_async  it will scroll down to row 24, with dispatch_after (2 sec) it scrolls to 22. Still not number 36 like I want it to.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your solution as a separate answer instead of as an edit to Nirav D's answer - that makes his/your answer very confusing. And maybe explain why his answer wasn't sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your requirement is to scroll to the last `cell` of `tableView` you can use `setContentOffset` like this so that you can scroll to the last cell of `tableView`.

Put this in the reloadData() function:

```
func reloadData(){
    chatroomTableView.reloadData()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.chatroomTableView.contentSize.height - self.chatroomTableView.frame.size.height)
        self.chatroomTableView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    })
}
```

Add this to your UITableViewDelegate :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)
        if indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1 {
            tableView.scrollToBottom(true)
        }
    }
```

Add this to the bottom of your .swift file:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        let sections = self.numberOfSections
        let rows = self.numberOfRowsInSection(sections - 1)
        if (rows > 0){
            self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: rows - 1, inSection: sections - 1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```